# How to pass variables to tab path in meteoric (Meteor, Ionic)

Tags: javascript, meteor, ionic-framework, meteoric

The tech stack I am using for the following is Meteor with https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic/

Please have in mind the following scenario:

A record lives in `/record/fancyRecordId`. I'd like to link to `/record/fancyRecordId/photos`. I am using the `ionTab` component, but I just can't figure out how to pass the id variable.

The code I have is as follows:

```
{{#ionTabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top"}}
  {{> ionTab title="Information" path="information" iconOff="checkmark-circled" iconOn="checkmark-circled"}}
  {{> ionTab title="Photos" path="profilePhotos" iconOff="person" iconOn="person"}}
{{/ionTabs}}
```

Could you please help me out?

Comment: you pass variables through the router, so we would need to see additional code to provide assistance

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I will do that on Monday!